# Creating directions from current location to destination using @capacitor/geolocation

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I wanted to show maps from users current location to the destination with live tracking (just like ola or uber)

I followed the steps as mentioned in Ionic guide book, below is my code

```
  async printCurrentPosition () {
    const coordinates = await Geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
  
    console.log('Current position:', coordinates); // prints users current location
  };



 async createMap() { //this displays the map
    this.newMap = await GoogleMap.create({
      id: 'my-cool-map',
      element: this.mapRef.nativeElement,
      apiKey: APIkey,
      config: {
        center: {
          lat: 33.6,
          lng: -117.9,
        },
        zoom: 8,
      },
    });
  }
```

Now, I do not know how to setup live tracking there is no document on how this can be using `@capacitor/google-maps`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the geolocation plugin and use the listener method to get the location of the device when it changes.

Comment: can you provide with some basic code,

Comment: No, there are many tutorials online how to do this. You need to search.